# Quero que ao passar o mouse por uma Li, o resultado apareça na DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero que, ao passar o mouse por uma `li`, o resultado apareça na `div`

colocando o mouse no Filho 2:
exemplo: Pai 1 > Filho 2

ou no Pai 2:
Pai 2

```
<li ><a href="#estaEm">Pai 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li ><a href="#estaEm">Pai 2</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</div>
<div id="estaEm" value ="">resultado </div>
```

O jQuery que fiz não funciona caso para aparecer apenas o Pai 2:

```
$( "li" ).bind( "mouseover", function() {
    var result=''

    $( this ).find("a").each(function () {
        result += " > " + $( this ).text()
    });

    $("#estaEm").text(result)
});
```

Comment: não entendi direito a sua dúvida, você gostaria de algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/k214LLdj/ tente ser mais claro.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('li > a')` como seletor no jQuery para pegar o(s) filho(s) de **li** e use `this` e pegue o texto da `li` que o mouse passou, é bem simples.

## Veja:

```js
$('li > a').mouseover(function() {
  $('#estaEm').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
   <li ><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li >
   <a href="#estaEm">Pai 2</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#estaEm" >Filho 1</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</div>
<div id="estaEm" value ="">resultado </div>
```

Comment: Tá errado pq se passar o mouse no pai 2
Aparece pai 2 filho 1
Deveria ser apenas pai 2